# Skyrim on new PC

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, mods, steam-workshop

I was reading through threads on here about transferring modded Skyrim from one pc to the next, and hit a little roadblock. All of my mods were from the workshop, and I believe I used NMM for that? It's fuzzy. It's been a long time since I played. I always started the game through something other than the Steam window, and it was SKSE. It would have this little splash screen and it checked all my mods, then once it was done I pressed start.

Anyway, I assumed that since they were workshop mods, that when I reinstalled on my new pc that they'd automatically come with it, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I totally didn't mind having to start a new character, but none of my mods were anywhere to be found. Will installing some sort of mod manager bring them back, or do I need to go spend an evening re-subbing to all the ones I had (if I even remember them all, lol)? Does Steam save what I've subbed to anywhere?

((I am able to access my old hdd, but I was warned to only do that if I truly must. My reason for the new pc was the old hdd was dying, as were many other components of it. My old hdd is in a casing and I had to jump through a ton of windows permission hissy-fits to take what I could off it the first time. It's possible to take files off it if I must, but I'd rather that be a last resort. I was told if I access the old one too much it may corrupt things or actually die.))

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of a conflict in what you're saying here. There are various ways to go about modding Skyrim; one of them being through the Steam Workshop.

But then you also mention NMM - Nexus Mod Manager.  NMM is a separate modding system, where you first download the Mod Manager itself and then download mods from the [Nexus Mod Manager community site](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/?) via NMM.

Your Steam Workshop mod subscriptions would (should) follow you anywhere. Your NMM mods would not. So if that's what you used, you would have to download them again.

Comment: Also, if you were unwise enough to mix the two... Ouch. Your best bet: Unsub from all mods in the workshop, delete local content for Skyrim, then reinstall clean and use NMM or Mod Organizer to track and keep clean your mod lists...

Comment: You can also get a list of (most) mods you used to have by using a tool such as Wrye Bash that can list your savefile's “masters”. (I say “most”, because it will only list mods that use .esps or .esms to change game contents; it won't list SKSE mods or texture/model/UI replacers, as those usually don't have an .esp/m and so don't get stored in your savefile.)

Comment: Interesting! I'm trying so hard to remember which I used. I remember finding them in the steam workshop to start with. Most of them just made the landscape/cities more beautiful, and I had a few "cheat" types for ease of use, like dragon bones not weighing anything and a vendor that would appear when I put on a ring. Also a more customizable character creation screen.

Comment: I guess I'll have to look and see what the deal was. I never saw or read anything that said mixing was a bad idea. Is there any way to tell? Does NMM only do Skyrim? Perhaps I had it for some other game. I guess I need to chk!

Comment: So I found the addons I subbed to on the workshop, and I'm still subbed, yet they're not appearing anywhere for me to load them. There doesn't seem to be a button to redownload them so they must be somewhere right?

Comment: According to https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/558746089050408723/ - the user in question had to unsub/resub all mods to get it to work for the workshop.

Answer (score 0):

If you subscribed to the mods in the steam workshop you should be able to at least look them up. Not sure what you used the NMM for then but on the nexus site you can look up your download history if you mixed mods from both sources.
The easiet way seems to be to just copy the Skyrim folder from your old HDD though.